# Does WorkManager.updateWork() need the full config or can it be partial?

Tags: android, android-workmanager

It's not clear to me from the [docs](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/work/WorkManager#updateWork(androidx.work.WorkRequest)) and [guidance](https://developer.android.com/guide/background/persistent/how-to/update-work) whether the `WorkRequest` passed to `updateWork()` (or to `enqueueUniquePeriodicWork()` with policy `ExistingPeriodicWorkPolicy.UPDATE`) must provide a full config, or whether it can be partial.

For example, if I want to update the config for a periodic work to change *only* one or more tags (added via `addTag()`) or one or more data items (set via `setInputData()`), but leave everything else alone (e.g. the network constraint, set via `setConstraints()`), then do I have to specify *everything* again (including the network constraint and the interval), or is it possible to update one one part of it?

For a `PeriodicWorkRequest` (which is required for the `updateWork()` or `UPDATE`), the `Builder` requires the `repeatInterval` to be specified in [the constructor](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/work/PeriodicWorkRequest.Builder#Builder(java.lang.Class,java.time.Duration)), so we must at least have to specify that again (even if it hasn't changed).  So I suspect that we *do* have to provide the full config for an `UPDATE`, not just those bits we want to update?

Answer (score 0):

Credit to `se...@google.com` [over on issuetracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/287633350#comment7) for this answer:

> `update` function meant to receive the whole config, so tags will be cleared if none were provided.

Note also the following observation:

> It is actually brings up some inconsistency in design of the `setNextScheduleTimeOverride`, that should be more seriously assessed and probably behavior should be unified.